# Hanging Letter Program

Tags: java, string

I was practicing problems in JAVA for the last few days and I got a problem like this:

```
I/p: I Am A Good Boy

O/p:

I A A G B
  m   o o
      o y
      d
```

This is my code.

```java
System.out.print("Enter sentence: ");
String s = sc.nextLine();
s+=" ";
String s1="";
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if(c!=32)
    {s1+=c;}
    else
    {
        for(int j=0;j<s1.length();j++)
        {System.out.println(s1.charAt(j));}
        s1="";
    }
}
```

The problem is I am not able to make this design.My output is coming as each character in each line.

Comment: You're using `println` to output each character; `println` always starts a new line after it prints whatever you've told it to print.  Output your characters with `print` instead and use `println()` (with nothing in the parens) to add line breaks when you need them.

Comment: Yes am using println() because **s1** is representing each word from that particular string **s** & according to my problem for each word I think I've to use println() but How can I move the next word to that position after ending of the previous word

Comment: You need to divide your strings with space as a delimiter, then you can process through the array of strings.

Comment: @YouKnowWhoIAm I have now tried what u told but cant make that pattern. i dont think using array or not using it will make any difference cz **charAt()** is working like that. The main thing is after making word hand we have to return to the initial position(starting position) and create a space & then again hang another word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to divide your string with space as a delimiter and store them in an array of strings, you can do this by writing your own code to divide a string into multiple strings, Or you can use an inbuilt function called `split()`

After you've 'split' your string into array of strings, just iterate through the array of strings as many times as your longest string appears, because that is the last line you want to print ( as understood from the output shared) i.e., `d` from the string `Good`, so iterate through the array of strings till you print the last most character in the largest/ longest string, and exit from there.

You need to handle any edge cases while iterating through the array of strings, like the strings that does not have any extra characters left to print, but needs to print spaces for the next string having characters to be in the order of the output.

Following is the piece of code that you may refer, but remember to try the above explained logic before reading further,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] s = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        // Split is a String function that uses regular function to split a string, 
        // apparently you can strings like a space given above, the regular expression 
        // for space is \\s or \\s+ for multiple spaces
        int max = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++) max = Math.max(max,s[i].length()); // Finds the string having maximum length
        int count = 0;
        while(count<max){ // iterate till the longest string exhausts
            for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                if(count<s[i].length()) System.out.print(s[i].charAt(count)+" "); // exists print the character
                else System.out.print("  "); // Two spaces otherwise
            }
            System.out.println();count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I am sharing the output below for the string `This is a test Input`

```
T i a t I 
h s   e n 
i     s p 
s     t u 
        t
```